# How do I do a a,b,c = x.split(" ") without it crashing when only a and b can be assigned?

Tags: python

```
a = munching mcdonalds

a,b,c = a.split(" ")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "terminal.py", line 25, in <module>
    a,b,c = a.split(" ")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

What code should I use instead if I want it to be either 2 or 3 words and still be able to print `a`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`split()` return a list. Therefore it should be use as one:

```
a = "munching mcdonalds"
b = a.split(" ")

>>>b
['munching', 'mcdonalds']
>>>b[0]
'munching' 
>>>b[1]
'mcdonalds'
```

Comment: Why?  If the OP only needs the first element from the split, then why shouldn't he just grab that and be done with it?

Comment: I am pretty sure he wants all the elements.

Comment: Not necessarily, as he asked, *"What code should I use instead if I want it to be either 2 or 3 words and still be able to print `a`?"*  However, assuming you are correct, why should he use the results as a list?  It's a common idiom to break up the members of a tuple or list into individual variables for convenience.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't actually *need* `b` or `c`, you could do something like:

```
>>> sentence = 'munching macdonalds'
>>> first, rest = sentence.split(' ', 1)
>>> first
'munching'
>>> rest
'macdonalds'
```

This uses the `maxsplit` parameter of `str.split` (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)) to limit to splitting on the first space.

You can then do e.g. `if ' ' in rest:` to determine whether the second part can be further split up.

---

If you're using Python 3, you can use the `*` notation to do the whole split, making `first` a string and `rest` a list:

```
>>> sentence = 'munching macdonalds'
>>> first, *rest = sentence.split(' ')
>>> first
'munching'
>>> rest
['macdonalds']
>>> sentence = 'foo bar baz'
>>> first, *rest = sentence.split(' ')
>>> first
'foo'
>>> rest
['bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 1):

This version is easily repeatable and gives you values for **all** your variables on the left, in case you decide that you want to use them later (not just `a`).  Note that it also does **not** modify the original list, so that it can be used as needed later.

```
def pad(iterable, length=0, padding=None):
    li = list(iterable)  # Generate new list from `iterable`.
    li.extend([padding] * (length - len(li)))  # Negative value generates empty list...
    return li

sentence = 'munching mcdonalds'
a, b, c = pad(sentence.split(), 3)
assert (a, b, c) == ('munching', 'mcdonalds', None)
a, b, c, d = pad(range(3), 4)
assert (a, b, c, d) == (0, 1, 2, None)
a = pad(range(4), 3)
assert a == [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

## Updated Answer

I thought about this after I made my initial post, and then myaut also pointed
out in a comment that it can be dangerous to generate this as a list.  What if
we want to pad it to, say, 1E30 elements or so? So here's the function as a
generator.

```
def pad(iterable, length=0, padding=None):
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
    for _ in range(length - len(iterable)):
        yield padding

sentence = 'munching mcdonalds'
a, b, c = pad(sentence.split(), 3)
assert (a, b, c) == ('munching', 'mcdonalds', None)
a, b, c, d = pad(range(3), 4)
assert (a, b, c, d) == (0, 1, 2, None)
a = list(pad(range(4), 3))
assert a == [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Thanks, myaut!

Comment: Cool idea! Shamefully, you can't get number of items to be extracted and have to pass them manually. But I think generating `list` is harmful. You can rewrite `pad()` as generator, i.e. `c = 0;
    for i in iterable:
        c += 1, yield i ; 
    for i in range(length - c):
        yield padding;`.

Comment: I had actually thought about that just a few minutes ago, but hadn't followed up yet.  I got to thinking about what would happen if someone wanted to pad it to, say, 1E30 elements or so, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Well... If you *really* want it:

```
a, b, c = [value if index >= len(a.split(' ')) else a.split(' ')[index] 
           for index, value in enumerate([None] * 3)]
```

Comment: But, of course, this is ugly and you shouldn't write code like this. Probably a bit less bad solution will be to have a function like ```safe_tuple(elements, elements_count, default_value=None)```, but it doesn't look good too.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, you can assign an arbitrary number of elements to the *last* item of a tuple unpacking.

```
>>> a, *b = "munching mcdonalds".split()
>>> a
munching
>>> b
['mcdonalds']
```